# "return" multiple values with &-operator but with no pointer: How does this work?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, variables, return-value

I'm sorry if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find a similiar question/example in the net.

I'm currently visiting C++ lectures at the university (since i have to), I already have relatively good expirience with the C-language from previous lectures.

Yesterday at the lecture I saw something curious: We discusse how to return multiple variables within a function without using pointers. In C I would code it like this (with pointers used):

```
// main.c 

#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *addr_val_var1, int *addr_val_var2);

int main()
{
  int var1, var2;

  foo(&var1, &var2);
  printf("Results: %d %d \n", var1, var2);
}

void foo(int *addr_val_var1, int *addr_val_var2)
{
  *addr_val_var1 = 5;
  *addr_val_var2 = 7;
}
```

However, my professor says we are not allowed to use pointers, and this is his solution:

```
// main.cpp 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// forward declarations
void foo(int &var1, int &var2);

int main()
{
    int var1, var2;

    foo(var1, var2);
    cout << "Results: " << var1 << " " << var2 << endl;

}

void foo(int &var1, int &var2)
{
    var1 = 5;
    var2 = 7;
}
```

How does this method work? I already tried the same within C but there it doesn't work. As far as I know the &-operator (at least in C) gives the address of the variable as a parameter and then (normally) awaits a pointer variable to work (=return by address)- but in C++ this also somehow works differently?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

OK it also works in C, but how? I didn't know this method at all and haven't found any reference?

Comment: You question is very basic and broad. You should read about c++ reference. In C reference does not exist.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP should just read its textbook, where (I am sure) the topic about passing by reference in C++ is explained, and what is the difference between passing by reference and passing by pointer. This is not the programming question. it is just elementary language knowledge

Comment: This method is call by reference. you can find good explanations about it. for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm

Comment: You do not return anything. Function ``foo(int &var1, int &var2)`` is marked as void which means it's not meant to return anything. The parameters do the trick. You can think of references as dereferenced pointers. Read on pass by reference vs pass by value. There are plenty of sources online on that.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages with a subset of syntax and semantics that is similar. You should not be surprised if somethings is valid in C++ but not in C. Different language, different rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe (as I am not a C++ programmer) that

```
void foo(int &var1, int &var2)
```

means that variables `var1` and `var2` are "references". It is a syntactic way of saying the vars are passed by reference and not by value. In the body the compiler now uses the reference as in `var= 5;`. It de-references that variable and then assigns to it.

Of course on the lower level this will be implemented as pointers.

Comment: passing-by-reference and passing-by-pointer are distinct is C++ and behave different way in C++. Answer is very imprecise and confusing. In C there is no pass-by-reference only pass-by-pointer i the C++ understanding and your explanation is in many places wrong. Passing-by-reference is safe

Comment: @P__J__, I removed my opinion.